# Firefox native JSON.parse cannot parse nested array property

Tags: arrays, json, firefox, nested

Native JSON.parse seems to have a poor implementation in FF (version in use 13.0.1), I've tried the following test code in IE, Chrome and FF. First 2 browsers seem to correctly parse json string to an Object while FF doesn't.

```
var jsonObj = { 
        onetype: [
            {id:1,name:"First Name"},
            {id:2,name:"Second Name"}
        ]
};
var serializedJsonObj = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(jsonObj));
serializedJsonObj.onetype[1].name;
```

I assume "Second Name" must be printed to output, but instead of this FF just prints 'undefined' since obj.onetype property is actually a string, to parse it into an object we must call again JSON.parse on it:

```
var jsonObj = { 
        onetype: [
            {id:1,name:"First Name"},
            {id:2,name:"Second Name"}
        ]
};
var serializedJsonObj = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(jsonObj));
JSON.parse(serializedJsonObj.onetype)[1].name;
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: Where have you tried that exactly? Sounds like a console issue.

Comment: The first code example works as intended for me. Why do you believe that `obj.onetype` is a string?

Comment: Thanks guys for your insights - sorry for bothering. Updated the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was out-of-date Prototype.js library included in the lib.js (Whoever would do this??). After reading 2 comments claiming this behavior in my case is not valid I created a test page with the real case where I've been experiencing the issue to test it, but it's not reproducible any longer.